# Overflow with flex-basis and min and max-width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My goal is to use flexbox to implement a slider that has a given width and can grow as items(images) are added into it, until a specific width is reached. After that width is reached i want to show a scrollbar on the x axis. I also want the slider not to shrink bellow the min-width.

This is what i tried:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="thisDivAllowsSliderToGrowToMaxWidth">
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="image"></div>
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center
}

.slider {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-start;
  height:100px;
  flex-basis: 250px;
  min-width:200px;
  max-width:350px;
  overflow-x:auto;
}

.image {
  flex-shrink:0;
  height:100px;
  width:50px;
}
```

The issue that pops out is that as soon as overflow-x is added to the slider, it does not grow anymore but shows the scrollbar as soon as flex-basis width is reached.

Interestingly, adding a simple wrapping div (.thisDivAllowsSliderToGrowToMaxWidth) around the slider somehow fixes the issue. You can find the example [here](https://jsbin.com/pusenorawi/edit?html,css,output).

Can anyone answer why is this happening and am I using the flex properties as intended?

Comment: There should be a working code snippet within the question, not only external linked resources.

Comment: Edited with more details, wanted to keep the question as short as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the flex container grow based on the width of the flex items, you can set the `flex-basis` to `content`

`content` will automatically size based on the flex item's content

```js
$(".add-slide").on("click",function(){

$(".slider").append('<div class="image"></div>');

});
```

```css
    .wrapper {
      height: 300px;
      border :1px solid red;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items:center
    }

    .slider {
      display:flex;
      border: 1px solid black;
      height:100px;
      flex-basis: content;
      min-width:200px;
      max-width:350px;
      overflow-x:auto;
      overflow-y:hidden;
    }

    .image {
      flex-shrink: 0;
      border: 1px solid green;
      height:100px;
      width:50px;
    }

    button {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
<button class="add-slide">add slide</button>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="image"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding display:flex to .thisDivAllowsSliderToGrowToMaxWidth returns us to the original issue where the scroll bar is shown as soon as you have items that fill the flex-basis width. My goal is to show the scroll bar only when the max-width is filled.

Comment: your questions was "Can anyone answer why is this happening and am I using the flex properties as intended?"

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear. My intention is to find an answer why is the flexbox refusing to grow without the non-flex wrapper div. Nevertheless thanks for the answer.

Comment: with the flexbox wrapper, it abides by the `flex-basis` of 250px -------  with the non-flex wrapper the `flex-basis` doesnt apply, so it stretches to the `max-width` of 350px since `div` is a block level element

Comment: My understanding of flex-basis was wrong. I thought that it is a desired size that will adjust based on the content, limited by min and max values. What actually helps in my case is to ditch the .thisDivAllowsSliderToGrowToMaxWidth and then set the flex-basis property of slider to flex-basis:content, while defining the min and max width values. This will make the slider grow with the content while respecting the overflow. Thanks very much for the help. If you edit your answer and include flex-basis:content, i ll be glad to accept it.

Comment: ive updated my answer and included an example with adding slides